# How to group at more than one level?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">222222222222</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">1></field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X333</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

From this xml file I should group field2 (after that  field4 ), question will be not to how to group field 2 and get three documents but how to group field4 if they are the same?

Output:

```
<document>
<Result>
    <Header>
        <Field2>X111</Field2>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Position>1</Position>
        <Field4>222222222222</Field4>
        <Sum>1<Sum>
        <Position>2</Position>
        <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
        <Sum>1<Sum>
    </Line>
</Result>
<Result>
    <Header>
        <Field2>X222</Field2>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Position>1</Position>
        <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
        <Sum>2<Sum>
    </Line>
</Result>
<Result>
    <Header>
        <Field2>X333</Field2>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Position>1</Position>
        <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
        <Sum>1</Sum>
    </Line>
</Result>
</document>
```

I'm stuck in grouping lines, I didn't know how to group the same and different fields which id= 4.

My program looks:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kLine" match="line" use="string(field[@id=2])"/>
    <xsl:key name="bLine" match="line" use="field[@id=4]"/>
    <xsl:template match="document">
        <document>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line[count( . | key('kLine', string(field[@id='2']))[1]) = 1]"/>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <xsl:variable name="field2" select="field[@id='2']"/>
        <result>
            <Header>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='2']"/>
            </Header>
            <Line>
            <xsl:for-each select="//line[field[@id='2']=$field2]">
                <Position>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </Position>
                <Field4><xsl:value-of select="field[@id='4']"/></Field4>
                <Sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('bLine', field[@id='4'])/field[@id='3'])"/></Sum>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </Line>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking how to group at multiple levels. The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="byField2" match="line" use="field[@id='2']" />
    <xsl:key name="byField2AndField4" match="line"
             use="concat(field[@id='2'], '|', field[@id='4'])" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <document><xsl:apply-templates /></document>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="line[generate-id() = 
                    generate-id(key('byField2', field[@id='2'])[1])]">
        <Result>
            <Header>
                <Field2><xsl:value-of select="field[@id='2']" /></Field2>
            </Header>
            <Line>
                <xsl:apply-templates
                    select="key('byField2', field[@id='2'])
                         [generate-id() =
                          generate-id(key('byField2AndField4',
                             concat(field[@id='2'], '|', field[@id='4']))[1])]"
                    mode="field4" />
            </Line>
        </Result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line" mode="field4">
        <Position><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></Position>
        <Field4><xsl:value-of select="field[@id='4']" /></Field4>
        <Sum>
            <xsl:value-of
              select="sum(key('byField2AndField4',
                 concat(field[@id='2'], '|', field[@id='4']))/
                     field[@id='3'])" />
        </Sum>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On this input:

```
<document>
    <line id="0">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">222222222222</field>
    </line>
    <line id="1">
        <field id="2">X111</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="2">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="3">
        <field id="2">X222</field>
        <field id="3">1></field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
    <line id="4">
        <field id="2">X333</field>
        <field id="3">1</field>
        <field id="4">111111111111</field>
    </line>
</document>
```

Produces the desired result:

```
<document>
    <Result>
        <Header>
            <Field2>X111</Field2>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <Position>1</Position>
            <Field4>222222222222</Field4>
            <Sum>1</Sum>
            <Position>2</Position>
            <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
            <Sum>1</Sum>
        </Line>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Header>
            <Field2>X222</Field2>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <Position>1</Position>
            <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
            <Sum>2</Sum>
        </Line>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Header>
            <Field2>X333</Field2>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <Position>1</Position>
            <Field4>111111111111</Field4>
            <Sum>1</Sum>
        </Line>
    </Result>
</document>
```

We use two keys. The first groups only by field 2. The second groups by the concatenation of fields 2 and 4.

Comment: @lwburk: There is a missing `[1]` predicate in the second key selection.

Comment: @Alejandro - Funny you should mention it. I noticed that a few minutes ago and was surprised it had worked in my previous tests. Re-reading the spec, I see that `generate-id` returns the ID for the first node in the set in document order, which is why this still works as expected. Is there some advantage to including the additional `[1]` predicate?

Comment: @lwburk: Other reason than readability is that node set implicit casting to singleton is not part of XPath 2.0 thus it raise an error. This is a good thing because silent implicit casting might hide some logic errors.

Comment: @Alejandro - Updated, based on the readability argument, which is compelling enough. However, I'm confused by your other reason. The behavior I describe is outlined in the XSLT 1.0 recommendation: "The generate-id function returns a string that uniquely identifies the node in the argument node-set that is first in document order."

Comment: @lwburk: From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-incompat-in-false-mode : _"When a node-set containing more than one node is supplied as an argument to a function or operator that expects a single node or value, the XPath 1.0 rule was that all nodes after the first were discarded. Under XPath 2.0, a type error occurs if there is more than one node. The XPath 1.0 behavior can always be restored by using the predicate `[1]` to explicitly select the first node in the node-set."_ But again, this is just style and conventions...

Comment: @Petras - You're welcome. And thanks to @Alejandro, once again, for providing additional information and improvements.